# convert hash in c# to php sockets

Tags: c#, php, sockets, hash, converters

I have this function in C#.

```
public static implicit operator Guid(TCPPacketReader p)
{
    byte[] tmp = new byte[16];
    Array.Copy(p.Data.ToArray(), p.Position, tmp, 0, tmp.Length);
    p.Position += 16;

    using (MD5 md5 = MD5.Create())
        tmp = md5.ComputeHash(tmp); //wtf?

    return new Guid(tmp);
}
```

I'm trying to replicate this functionality in PHP. The problem is that when I get this tmp variable in array. it return something like:

```
array[5, 49, 42, 5, 254, 160, 191, 64, 79, 37, 216, 169, 201, 181, 13, 0, 59, 187]
```

and i really don't know how to do this computeHash(tmp) in php. I've tried it with md5() PHP's function but return a null object. i'm googled a lot but nothing successful. Anyone know how to do that?

Comment: Seems that you have an array of character.  I'm not a php expert or anything, but you need to convert to a string somehow before passing it to md5().  try mdf(implode(" ",$array))

Comment: this array is an guid array bytes. and this function in c# converts to guid in string again. i'm tryind do the same in php. let try do this to see if work.

Answer (score 0):

First: `MD5.Create().ComputeHash(tmp);` makes it a bit more readable (in this case)

What C# does is take an array of bytes. What PHP does, is take a string. If you want the input for PHP to be an array of bytes, you first have to convert it to a string

```
$tmp = md5(implode(array_map("chr", $tmp)));
// the implode and array_map turn tmp into a string, from an array containing the byte's ASCII codes (1-255)
```

C# `md5.ComputeHash(tmp)` returns an array of bytes of the hash

PHP `md5(tmp)` returns a string containing the hexadecimal representation of the hash

since you provided no code for PHP, i can't answer the question. But this should get you on your way.

Comment: the c# get the hash in string and convert to byte array[16] i do the same thing with php using unpack("C*", {hash}) but when i try return using this code, it does not work.

Comment: `$guid = "{4fa7189c-89a0-0500-cb1a-923d2ad914be}";                          $guid = unpack("C*", $guid);                                                                  //new guid : 1235210297554956579945565797484548534848459998499745575051100509710057495298101125
$newGuid = '';
  foreach($guid as $g)
   $newGuid .= $g;
md5(implode(array_map("chr", $newGuid))) // return : d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e`